# Set Inverval quando $on for definido

Tags: angularjs

Galera, to apanhando aqui para fazer um interval rsrs.

```
$rootScope.$on("timer", updateApanha());

 var arquivoJSON = (JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('timeUpdate'))*1000);

console.log(tempoDeAtualizacao);

function updateApanha(){
setInterval(getApanha, tempoDeAtualizacao);
console.log("get Apanha " +tempoDeAtualizacao);
   }
```

A questao é que o interval ele é setado como undefined. E por conta disso ele fica fazendo a requisição toda hora. O que eu queria era que somente quando fosse chamado $on que fosse setado o interval para poder chamar a função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente remover os parenteses da função `updateApanha`, assim ela será somente atribuída ao evento `timer` e não executada.

```
$rootScope.$on("timer", updateApanha);
```

Comment: Dessa forma resolveu o meu problema. Somente atribuir a função ao evento.Ty

Answer (score 1):

A linha

```
$rootScope.$on("timer", updateApanha());
```

Significa: *Quando a mensagem `timer` for emitida, execute **o resultado** da função `updateApanha`.*

Isso faz com que `UpdateApanha` seja executada ao menos uma vez, e imediatamente.